# Unable to use scapy as a bridge among interfaces

Tags: python, security, networking, scapy, man-in-the-middle

I'm trying to perform a transparent MITM attack with scapy. I've got an Ubuntu machine with two network interfaces, connected each one to a machine. Those machines have same subnet addresses and operate correctly if directly connected. The objective is to be able to be totally transparent, using both interfaces with no IP address and in promisc mode.

The implementation I'm using is the following:

```
def pkt_callback(pkt):
    if pkt.sniffed_on == "enp0s3":
        sendp(pkt, iface="enp0s8", verbose=0)
    else:
        sendp(pkt, iface="enp0s3", verbose=0)

def enable_bridge():
    sniff(iface=["enp0s3", "enp0s8"], prn=pkt_callback, store=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf.sniff_promisc=True
    enable_bridge()
```

This is not all the code, but is the main routing part... I can see that packets arrive to both interfaces, but no pinging from one machine to another... Any idea of how to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

The full implementation here:

```
from scapy.all import *
from utils import interfaces, addresses
#from routing import *
from packet_filters import is_mms_packet
from attacks import performAttack
import sys
import os
import time
import datetime

def writePacketInDisk(pkt):
    wrpcap("network_logs/network-log- 
    "+datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y")+"-"
        +datetime.date.today().strftime("%B")+"- 
    "+datetime.date.today().strftime("%d")+".pcap", pkt, append=True)

def pkt_callback_PLC_OPC(pkt):
    ret = True
#   if is_mms_packet(pkt):
#       writePacketInDisk(pkt)
    #ret = performAttack(pkt)
    return ret

def pkt_callback_OPC_PLC(pkt):
    ret = True
#   if is_mms_packet(pkt):
#       writePacketInDisk(pkt)
    #ret = performAttack(pkt)
    return ret

def enable_bridge():
    print "hello!!"
    bridge_and_sniff(interfaces["plc-ccb"], interfaces["opc"], 
        xfrm12=pkt_callback_PLC_OPC, xfrm21=pkt_callback_OPC_PLC,
         count=0, store=0)
    #prn = lamba x: x.summary()
    print "bye!!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf.sniff_promisc=True
    enable_bridge()
```

This is definitely not working... Is the code correct? May be my VM too slow for this task?

Comment: Thinking about the issue, I suppose the network interface itself, sends a response to the ping request... no matter what the scapy script is doing... Can this automatic behavior be disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is correct and should work. You should update to the current development version of Scapy (https://github.com/secdev/scapy/) and see if that was related to an old bug.

As a side note, you can directly use `bridge_and_sniff("enp0s3", "enp0s8")` instead of writing your own function.

Comment: I've switched to bridge_and_sniff and when I execute my code it just does nothing. It does not get stuck in bridge_and_sniff, program just finishes... I'm using the dev version now.

Comment: Use a `prn=lambda p: p.summary()` callback to see what happens.

Comment: Well, it does not get stuck now... But the problem is different now... I've checked if there's connection between MITM machine and both endpoints, each from a different interface, ant indeed, there is. But, when I try to ping from one endpoint to the other, it does not work. I can see by x.summary() that ARP requests are being sent, but no responses nor ICMP packets are shown...

Comment: I'm running this script in an Ubuntu VM with bridged physical interfaces... can this be a problem?

Comment: So... the politics of promisc mode in host machine were the problem.... I'm facing another issue now. bridge_and_sniff function suddenly stops and program terminates... Is this expected to happen?